# Why do you need to sometimes select object to avoid "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: vba, excel

I have noticed that I sometimes get the error:

> Run-time error '438':
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method

in Excel VBA but if I call `.select` on the object first then this error goes away.

For example, I recently wanted to change the size of some linked images on a work sheet and I recorded the following using the macro recorder:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 3")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 303.12
```

This code obviously works fine. I then altered the code as follows:

```
Dim sheetReport as Worksheet
Set sheetReport = Worksheets("Report")

With sheetReport
    Dim pictureNumber As Long
    For pictureNumber 1 to 3
        .Shapes.Range("Picture " & pictureNumber).ShapeRange.Height = 303.12
    Next pictureNumber
End With
```

And now I get the error mentioned above *however* if I then alter this code to

```
Dim sheetReport as Worksheet
Set sheetReport = Worksheets("Report")

With sheetReport
    Dim pictureNumber As Long
    For pictureNumber 1 to 3
        .Shapes.Range("Picture " & pictureNumber).Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 303.12
    Next pictureNumber
End With
```

It works again. But surely I shouldn't have to select each picture just to alter its `Height` property?

Comment: if you declare the worksheet by adding the workbook this may remedy the issue.  Currently, if you had multiple workbooks open, this would attempt to check the active workbook for the worksheet "report".  So if you created a workbook object and set the sheet by setting it equal to a sheet in the workbook object you may avoid this issue.  You wouldn't need to select anything or an active book because it would already have direction as to which specific location of the object you were referring to.

Comment: @StormsEdge I only have one worksheet open but I'll try it anyway, so you mean something like `Set sheetReport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")`

Comment: Just tried the code I posted in the previous comment, still gives me the same error

Comment: The macro is in the workbook you're attempting to manipulate correct?  (Apologies if that sounds like a stupid question, but you'd be surprised.)

Comment: @StormsEdge the one I'm testing is - but in the actual code it won't be. But either way, in this test case it is.

Comment: @StormsEdge but I can't imagine it's an issue of it not knowing which workbook to use because the last code block in the question works and that uses the same declaration for `sheetReport`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works fine in my test run.

```
 Sub PictureResizing()

      Dim sheetReport As Worksheet
      Set sheetReport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")

      Dim pictureNumber As Long

      With sheetReport

           For pictureNumber = 1 To 3

           .Shapes("Picture " & pictureNumber).Height = 303.12

           Next pictureNumber

      End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work for me. But can you explain why my code stops erroring if I call `.Select`?

Comment: @Dan, I believe it is because you are using `ShapeRange`. My understanding is the `ShapeRange` Object is for referring to a specific `Shape` in a `Selection` and when you want to refer to a specific `Shape` on the `Sheet` you will need to just use `Shape`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Late to the party, but basically `ShapeRange` is a property of an object (such as a selection) while `Shape`is an object itself. See [this for ShapeRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840131.aspx) and [this for Shapes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841148.aspx)